# why is node-postgres only working with routes

Tags: node.js, postgresql, node-postgres

I am currently trying to query some data from AWS RDS using postgresql and pg for node.js. For some reason, I found out I can only query data when I am using a route handler.

for example:

```
const data = require('../data/rand.json');
const db = require('../db');

const Router = require('express-promise-router');

const router = new Router();

module.exports = router;

router.get('/', (req,res) => {
    db.query(`SELECT * FROM rooms WHERE id < 10`)
    .then((val) => console.log(val))
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
})
```

However, when I try to query data like this:

```
const db = require('../db');

db.query(`SELECT * FROM rooms WHERE id < 10`)
    .then((val) => console.log(val))
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

I get this error - TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "key" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, TypedArray, DataView, or KeyObject. Received null

I am fine to continue using routes to query, but was wondering why this is occurring and if it is normal. I couldn't find much info on the [node-postgres](https://node-postgres.com/features/queries) docs. I am still new to this, thanks for any help.

edit: db file looks like this

```
const { Pool } = require('pg');

//don't need to add obj w/ env var inside Pool
const pool = new Pool();

//value - cb f(x)
module.exports = {
  query: (text, params) => pool.query(text, params),
}
```

Comment: Please show us the contents of your `db` module and point out the line where the exception comes from. My guess is you're doing some kind of asynchronous initialisation in there? The difference to the route is that the handler isn't called immediately on startup of the server.

Comment: hi Bergi, I edited my initial post with the db module. The line is: internal/crypto/keys.js:305
      throw new ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE(

Comment: I have been trying to run the file without the route like this, node non-routefile.js. So do I need to be connected to the server in order to query data?

Comment: Crypto? That's weird. Can you [edit] your question to include the entire stack trace, please?

Comment: No, the server should not be necessary. My guess is asynchronous initialisation of something. Can you try ``new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000)).then(() => db.query(`SELECT * FROM rooms WHERE id < 10`)).then(…)``?