# Query not returning results nor failing. Only gives back an unresolved Promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, node-postgres

This is confusing me a lot, because I'm repeating the code structure I have on other parts of my project (and it works there).

This is the part where it doesn't work:
/utils/socketQueries.js

```
const db = require('../db')

exports.addMessage = async (message) => {
    console.log('add message func', message)
    try {    
        /* const res = await db.query('select 1', (err, res) => {
            console.log(res)
        })*/  
        const res = await db.query('select 1') // this doesn't work either
        return res

    } catch (error) { console.error('adding message error', error) }
}
```

This is called from /socketserver.js

```
exports.socketServer = (wss) => {  
    let socket_id = new Map()
    
    wss.on("connection", (ws, req) => {
                    
        ws.on('message', (data) => { //messages from the client
            parseMessage(ws, socket_id, data)
        })
    })
...
```

this is how I set up the db connection in db.js

```
require('dotenv').config()

const { Pool } = require('pg')
const connectionString = process.env.DBCONNSTRING
const db = new Pool({
  connectionString: connectionString,
})

module.exports = db;
```

and an example of a working query function would be /api/health.js

```
const db = require('../db');

exports.check = async (req, res) => {
    let response = {
        apiResponsive: true
    }

    try {
        dbResponsive = await db.query(`select 1`)
        
        if (dbResponsive.rows[0]) response = {dbResponsive: true, ...response}
        else response = {dbResponsive: true, ...response} }
        
    catch(error) {
        console.error('error on db health check', error)
        response = {dbResponsive: 'error while checking', ...response}
    }

    res.json(response)
}
```

I've been trying different ways to run the query: .then, callback, async/await and it always returns either the unresolved promise or undefined - it never throws an error.

Can anyone sort out whats the (likely very basic) error I'm missing?

**EDIT:** Trying out the answers proposed I noticed that if I try an `INSERT` query, nothing is inserted on the DB. regardless of what I do with what `db.query` returns, the query should run.

Comment: In your addMessage function have you got async and await mixed up?

Comment: sorry about that, I mixed it only while editing the text before posting

Comment: Don't pass a callback to `db.query` when you expect to use the promise return value

Comment: I tried again, using the same format as in the working query and still doesn't work. What is also interesting, is that if I try an insert query, nothing is inserted on the DB. regardless of what I do with what db.query returns, the query should run. right?

Comment: Are you sure the client/pool is properly connected to the database? In the past, I remember similar suspicious problems could be resolved by updating `pg` to the latest version.

Comment: yes. I checked both in postgres itself and could see the connection from the app, and also the other endpoint I'm showing in the code works. which makes me suspect of something similar to this issue right here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66200318/why-is-node-postgres-only-working-with-routes/